# How do I preseed mixed LVM and regular partitions?

Tags: partitioning, system-installation, lvm, preseed

I'm trying to seed an installation to create the following partition scheme:

- `/dev/sda1` - /boot (Regular)
- `/dev/sda2` - SWAP (Regular)
- `/dev/sda3` - `/`
  (LVM)

For this, I'm using the preseed settings below:

```
...
d-i partman-auto/method string lvm
d-i partman-lvm/device_remove_lvm boolean true
d-i partman-lvm/confirm boolean true
d-i partman-lvm/confirm_nooverwrite boolean true

d-i partman-auto/expert_recipe string                         \
    pvs ::                                                    \
        250 250 250 ext4 $primary{ } $bootable{ }             \
        mountpoint{ /boot }                                   \
        method{ format }                                      \
        format{ }                                             \
        use_filesystem{ }                                     \
        filesystem{ ext4 }                                    \
        device{ /dev/sda1 }                                   \
        .                                                     \
        100% 512 100% linux-swap $primary{ }                  \
        method{ swap }                                        \
        format{ }                                             \
        device{ /dev/sda2 }                                   \
        .                                                     \
        1 1 -1 ext4 $primary{ }                               \
        $primary{ }                                           \
        method{ lvm }                                         \
        device{ /dev/sda3 }                                   \
        vg_name{ default }                                    \
          .                                                   \  
    lvm ::                                                    \
        4096 4096 -1 ext4 $primary { } $lvmok{ }              \
        mountpoint{ / }                                       \
        lv_name{ root }                                       \
        in_vg { default }                                     \
        method{ format }                                      \
        format{ }                                             \
        use_filesystem{ }                                     \
        filesystem{ ext4 }                                    \
        .                                                   
                                                      
d-i     partman-partitioning/confirm_write_new_label boolean true
d-i     partman/choose_partition select finish
d-i     partman/confirm boolean true
d-i     partman/confirm_nooverwrite boolean true
...
```

The installation succeeds, but the final layout is all inside LVM. It seems to ignore the `device{}` definitions.

Does anyone know how to mix regular and LVM partitions in a proper way?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

This is a recipe I've used.  It creates

- 512MB EFI System Partition
- 1GB /boot partition
- partition from the remaining space and LVM volume group
- logical volume for root (/)

```
d-i partman-auto/expert_recipe string \
        efi-boot-lvm-root :: \
              512 512 512 fat32 \
                      $primary{ } \
                      method{ efi } \
                      format{ } \
              . \
              1024 1024 1024 ext4 \
                      $primary{ } \
                      $bootable{ } \
                      method{ format } \
                      format{ } \
                      use_filesystem{ } \
                      filesystem{ ext4 } \
                      mountpoint{ /boot } \
              . \
              100 1000 1000000000 $default_filesystem \
                      $defaultignore{ } \
                      $primary{ } \
                      method{ lvm } \
                      device{ /dev/sda } \
                      vg_name{ vg-0 } \
              . \
              1024 3072 -1 $default_filesystem \
                      $lvmok{} \
                      lv_name{ lv-root } \
                      in_vg{ vg-0 } \
                      method{ format } \
                      format{ } \
                      use_filesystem{ } \
                      filesystem{ ext4 } \
                      mountpoint{ / } \
              .
```